# program stuck when reading file on.get function

Tags: c++, file-io, win32gui

I'm creating a program on win32, the program stops responding on .get function, I don't know what to do else, I think the problem is with `std::ifstream inFile;` but I need it outside of the main program, so I can use it in everywhere, for example here I use inFile in WM_CREATE and also in WM_KEYDOWN and close the file when the window closes. is it posible to do?

```
char Map[10][10], c[256];
std::ifstream inFile;

//windProc
case WM_CREATE: {
    inFile.open ("Map.txt");
    if (!inFile) {
       ::MessageBox(hwnd, "Failed to open file", "Error", MB_OK);
    }
    int i,j;
    do {                                             //loop for skipping comments
        Map[j][i] = inFile.get();                    //<---stuck here
        if (Map[j][i] ==';') inFile.getline(c, 256);     
    } while (Map[j][i] ==';');

    while (Map[j][i] !=';') {                        //loop for painting
        switch (Map[j][i]) {
        //
        //paint based on char
        //
        }
        i++;
        Map[j][i] = inFile.get();
        if (i==10) {j++; i=0;}
    }
}
case WM_KEYDOWN: {             
   //...
   inFile.getline(c, 256);                           // continue reading from file
   int j=0; int i=0;
   Map[j][i] = inFile.get();
   while (Map[j][i] !=';') {
        switch (Map[j][i]) {
        //
        //paint based on char
        //
        }
        i++;
        Map[j][i] = inFile.get();
        if (i==10) {j++; i=0;}
   }
break; }
case WM_DESTROY:
    inFile.close();
    PostQuitMessage (0);
break;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you're not initializing `i` and `j`. Try initializing them to `0`. Also, you presumably want to update them in your loop so you don't continuously store the character in the same element.

Then you need to reinitialize `i` and `j` to `0` before the painting loop. However, painting is usually done in `WM_PAINT` (I'm not even sure it'll work in `WM_CREATE`.)

Comment: yes, setting them to 0 works now, lol how I didn't noticed that, thankyou. 
                                                                  
I'm just using CreateWindow and setting them to display image, couldn't show whole program coz it takes too much space

Answer (score 1):

If the steam enters error/eof state in your while loop, `Map[j][i]` won't ever be set to `';'` resulting in an endless loop:

```
do {                                             //loop for skipping comments
    Map[j][i] = inFile.get();                    //<---stuck here
    if (Map[j][i] ==';') inFile.getline(c, 256);     
} while (inFile.good() && Map[j][i] ==';');
```

Comment: no the problem is it's not even looping, it just stops doing anything at all, I have even made a test on debug mode, after this line `Map[j][i] = inFile.get();` put `std::cout << "next";` but its not printing anything at all

Comment: Have you stepped through in the debugger?